# How to send a Parse Push notification to a specific user

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to make a Cloud code to send a Push Notification to a specific user.

The Parse user can have several installations.

I want to send the notification only to the First created User. I'm writing this cloud code function, but it seems to send push notifications to all the installation files and not to the recent one.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    var fromUser = new Parse.User({id:request.params.userId});
    query.equalTo("user", fromUser);
    query.equalTo("channels", "main");
    query.descending("createdAt");
    query.first({
    success: function(installation)
    {

     var device = installation.get("deviceType")    
     if (device == "ios") {
                Parse.Push.send({
      where : query,
      data : {
      title : title,
      alert: alert,
      sound : "chime", 
      badge: "Increment",
          }

      }, { success: function() { 
      response.success("Success");
      }, error: function(err) { 
       response.error(err);
      }
});
```

Comment: You can set the parse query limit to 1 and `addAscending` by creationDate to get the oldest matching installation.  Generally though it is safer to send to all of a user's installations because the oldest installation may be for a device they no longer have

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this in cloud code but in rest via python. You could query the users table to obtain first user then join to installations to obtain installation ID. Then place installation ID='the id you got from your join' in the where clause. Exact syntax is available in the docs.